# Manage the gmap embedded iframe initial zoom level

Tags: html, iframe

I integrate a gmap iframe on my website and i would like to know how to modify the zoom of the gmap ? How do i set a default zoom value ?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="Flexible-container">
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2624.090588107181!2d2.2261348518741295!3d48.87554960734967!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47e664de82918609%3A0x12912c17a8dd9551!2s83+Rue+Carnot%2C+92150+Suresnes%2C+France!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sch!4v1464688931681&z=20" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean manually define the zoom? Explain yourself. You want the user to be able to zoom in and out (that is available within iframe). You want to set a static zoom so the user can not change it again? You want to set a default zoom value?

Comment: I want to set a default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just zoomed out in gmap like i wished and then asked for the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the zoom in the initial script tags in the head of the file, below where you might include your css. An example of this would be what I have below.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(33.670230,-95.576964),
zoom:17,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

You can see on the sixth line there how the zoom is set to 17 (this makes about 2-3 blocks view-able). From what I can tell the line you're trying to edit is in the code near the bottom where you might include jquery or jscript. I believe this guide from google's developer network might be an aid for further instruction!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorials/adding-a-google-map

Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&z=nn` parameter (maybe `&zoom=nn` works too) **at the end** of your iframe `src` attribute.

***Note***: `nn` is the number you want to add. For instance : `&z=5`, or `&z=15`, or `&zoom=5`.

So given your source you have to change this:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2624.090588107181!2d2.2261348518741295!3d48.87554960734967!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47e664de82918609%3A0x12912c17a8dd9551!2s83+Rue+Carnot%2C+92150+Suresnes%2C+France!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sch!4v1464688931681&z=20
```

to whatever zoom number you want.

***Note***: Do you see the `&z=20` parameter in the end, of the source? This number is the default zoom level.

Please try it and comment me if you find any problems.